# Resolve TypeError "can only concatenate tuple (not 'int') to tuple" with function designed to return all summation compositions

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm trying to write a function in Python that returns a set of k-sized tuples that sum to n, and I'm fairly certain that I have the function written correctly, but I keep getting the type error that I mentioned in the title.

For example, compositions(3,4) should return the following:
{(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1)}

```py
def compositions(k, n):
    if k == 1:
        return (n,)
    comp = []
    for SumIterator in range(1, n+1):
        for FunctionRecall in compositions(k = k-1, n = n-SumIterator):
            comp.append((SumIterator,) + FunctionRecall)
    return set(comp)
```

Any idea on how to fix this function so that it runs correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is supposed to return a set of tuples, you'll need to revise your base case.

```
if k == 1:
    return (n,)
```

This doesn't return a set of tuples. It returns one tuple. Try putting it in a set.

```
if k == 1:
    return {(n,)}
```

Additionally, if you don't want any of the tuples to contain zero, I think you need to change the bounds of your first for loop to `for SumIterator in range(1, n):`.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, you're the man! I knew that I almost had it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for FunctionRecall in compositions(k = k-1, n = n-SumIterator):
        comp.append((SumIterator,) + FunctionRecall)
```

SumIterator is `1`; `(SumIterator,)` is the tuple `(1,)`.

Your inner `for` loop runs FunctionRecall through the elements of the `compositions` return, which is either a tuple or a set or integers.  Thus, when you get to this point, you have:

```
        comp.append((1,) + 2)
```

You cannot "add" a tuple and a scalar.  What did you want here ... a tuple composition?  That would be (1,) + (2,)